# How to sort a list in Python using two attribute values?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list named L and two attribute dictionaries named `arr1` and `arr2`, whose keys are the elements of the list `L`. Now I want to sort `L` in the following manner.

1. `L` should be sorted in ascending order by virtue of the attribute values present in `arr1`.
2. If two elements `i` and `j` of `L` have same attribute `arr1`, i,e, if `arr1[i]` and `arr[j]` are equal, then we should look for the attribute values in `arr2`.

To give an example, suppose

```
L=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr1={0:30,1:15,2:15,3:20,4:23,5:20,6:35}
arr2={0:6,1:8,2:6,3:17,4:65,5:65,6:34}
```

Sorted `L` should be `[2,1,3,5,4,0,6]`, ordering between 1 and 2 is decided by `arr2`, so does the ordering between 3 and 5. Rest of the ordering are decided by `arr1`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a tuple with the values from `arr1` and `arr2` as sort key:

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: (arr1[x], arr2[x]))
# [2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 6]
```

This is different from your expected result in the ordering of 5 and 3, which would be consistent if the sort order would be *descending* based on arr2:

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: (arr1[x], -arr2[x]))
# [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 0, 6]
```

But now the ordering of 1, 2 is different, your example doesn't seem to be ordered in a consistent way.

Comment: got it, thanks mate. I did a mistake in the in the final output.